# WCF use original domain object instead of proxy generated

Tags: wcf, object, proxy, dns

I have a Client website, a WCF service and a library of domain objects (.cproj).

I want the client to use my library of domain objects directly, not the proxy generated version of the domain objects. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Include a reference to the dll in your client project. Then add a Service Reference. When you add the service reference there is an option to use the types in the dll and not create them in the references.cs.

Answer (score 0):

Include the library project or DLL in your client project rather than creating a service reference.  You can generate the service reference to create all the necessary WCF configurations to call the service, but just don't use the generated proxy or datatypes (e.g. the code in Reference.cs) - use the types in the included DLL directly.  You may need to write a client yourself, but this is simple, and can be basically copied from the generated client in a service reference.

That said, sharing the datatypes directly between the client and service sort of breaks service-oriented architecture patterns.  Now both your client and service are dependent on the same DLL, rather than the client just being dependent on a service.